# AngularJS attempt to show div element based on hidden input value is not working

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to get my div elements to show based on a hidden input value according to the code below:

```
<form method="post">
  <fieldset data-ng-app="">
    <input type="hidden" id="Method" name="Method" value="1" data-ng-model="methodType" />
    <div data-ng-show="methodType=='1'">Method 1</div>
    <div data-ng-show="methodType=='2'">Method 2</div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

None of the div elements are being displayed when the page is loaded. It seems to work when I change the type of the input to "text", but then I had to manually type in the value into the field to get it to show/hide accordingly. May I get help with this?

Comment: Setting value does not automatically ng-model, since that is not the way angular works. You generally don't deal with value instead you just deal with model and bindings...

Comment: I also don't see a controller definition, which I'm used to seeing.

Comment: @rchang: I've seen examples on the WWW where you don't need the controller. Furthermore it seems to work when I changed the input type to "text".

Comment: When the input is set to text, the ng-model "methodType" is actually being set when you type in a number. Right now as you have it, the ng-model "methodType" is just an empty model, hence the div's not toggling as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular won't recognise setting the model to a value unless the input is interacted with — such as on a radio button.

If what you are trying to do is to set the model value on load, set it in a controller, or use `data-ng-init` instead of a hidden input.

```
<form method="post">
  <fieldset data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="methodType = 1">
    <div data-ng-show="methodType == 1">Method 1</div>
    <div data-ng-show="methodType == 2">Method 2</div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```